# How to overplot arrays of different shape?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to overplot two arrays with different shapes but I'm unable to project one on the top of the other. For example:

```
#importing the relevant packages
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def overplot(data1,data2):
    '''
    This function should make a contour plot
    of data2 over the data1 plot.
    '''

    #creating the figure
    fig = plt.figure()

    #adding an axe
    ax = fig.add_axes([1,1,1,1])

    #making the plot for the
    #first dataset
    ax.imshow(data1)

    #overplotting the contours
    #for the second dataset
    ax.contour(data2, projection = data2,
               levels = [0.5,0.7])

    #showing the figure
    plt.show(fig)

    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''
    testing zone
    '''

    #creating two mock datasets
    data1 = np.random.rand(3,3)
    data2 = np.random.rand(9,9)

    #using the overplot
    overplot(data1,data2)
```

Currently, my output is something like:

[image: example image]

While what I actually would like is to project the contours of the second dataset into the first one. This way, if I got images of the same object but with different resolution for the cameras I would be able to do such plots. How can I do that?

Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: If I understood right, yes. In the example there is no object to portrait but on the actual data both images would be showing the Sun so they need to be aligned in the same dimensions.

Comment: My bad, normalization won't help here because the main issue is the different dimensions. No straightforward answer at the moment in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally best to make the data match, and then plot it.  This way you have complete control over how things are done.

In the simple example you give, you could use repeat along each axis to expand the 3x3 data to match the 9x9 data.  That is, you could use, `data1b = np.repeat(np.repeat(data1, 3, axis=1), 3, axis=0)` to give:
[image]

But for the more interesting case of images, like you mention at the end of your question, then the axes probably won't be integer multiples and you'll be better served by a spline or other type interpolation.  This difference is an example of why it's better to have control over this yourself, since there are many ways to to this type of mapping.

Comment: In this case I'm working they actually are. So do you suggest me using which of the methods you mentioned ?

Comment: If they are integer multiples, repeat is easier to code and faster in the processor. At least it's a good place to start. Either way (repeat or spline) you're representing a single data point with many pixels, so you're coloring the view of the data no matter what you do, so it's a matter of taste (and maybe science) whether you want sharp or smooth boundaries.